# Using Fetch but have a key param at the end of the URL to GET and POST

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am using fetch but my company now has a `keyAccess` key param that I have to put at the end of the url to POST and GET.
I am not sure how to do this in either.

In my POST, I am sending data in the body already:

```
let myUrl = "http://www.example.com";
    fetch(myUrl, {
       method: "POST",
       headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
       }, 
       body: JSON.stringify(data);
    }
```

and in my GET, would I just append it to the url like? :

```
fetch(myUrl + 'keyAccess=938741')
```

Comment: GET parameters are just `key=value` pairs following `?` and separated by `&` in the URL. So `fetch(myUrl + '?keyAccess=938741')` would work if the URL doesn't already contain other GET parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [URL interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) to create your url and with the [searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) method you could append the key value pairs that you need. This way you don't have to check if the URL already has GET parameters.

```js
const url = new URL("http://www.example.com");
url.searchParams.append("keyAccess", 938741);

console.log(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

In get request the parameters send with the url at the end using ? Key=value for single parameter for multiple you use
Yoururl?key=value&key2=value2.... and so on.